# Windows Ink - UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a uwp app, and I'm using some code from this example from Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-coloringbook). In this example lets you choose an image from a collection with several images and then paint / write that image with Windows Ink. In resume: Main Page - "New Coloring Page" (WelcomePage.xaml) -> Choose collection (PickCollectionPage.xaml) -> Choose image (PickColoringPage.xaml) -> user can draw/paint (ColoringPage.xaml).
I want only this: Page - "New Coloring Page" (WelcomePage.xaml) -> user can draw/paint.
Instead of loading an image chosen by the user (as in the exemple) I want to just put a white background by default, and user can paint, write or draw in this white/empty background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of loading an image chosen by the user (as in the exemple) I want to just put a white background by default, and user can paint

What you actually want to do is much simpler than the sample "Coloringbook" can do. The paint relative features are implemented by [`InkCanvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas) associate with [`InkToolbar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inktoolbar) control. You just need to navigate from the `WelcomePage` to a new page that contains a `InkCanvas` with features you want without loading images. For this you can reference the scenario 2 of [SimpleInk](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk) official sample instead.

If you do want to generate your project based on "Coloringbook" sample app, you may do some changes for the code and delete the additional features. For example, changing the navigate page as follows,

```
 //WelcomePage
 private void Color_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ColoringPage));
     //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PickCollectionPage));
 }
```

and  deleting the  `OnNavigatedTo` method on `ColoringPage` which is for loading the images,  set `Height` and `Width` for `InkCanvas` instead of setting by `Image_Opened` method.

```
//ColoringPage.Xaml
<Viewbox>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="myInkCanvas" Height="500" Width="500"/>
</Viewbox>
```

All of the methods in `ColoringPage` that contain image relative code snippet should be updated.  For details work for updating the code snippet to meet your requirements please try it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really what I want!